# How Stack Overflow site executes very fast Ajax like functionalities?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, performance, process

I was wondering and very much curious that How Stack Overflow site is executing very very fast Ajax like functionalities?

> Because if see at the voting system, comments, answers, approve edits,
>   edits in answer and questions.

All these are working so fast I couldn't imagine that How SO executes these things very very quick. Because in our general scenario if we make Ajax Request it takes few seconds to respond but not in case of SO.

How this happens?

***Edit: for those who voted it to close***

Here my intention is only for technical person. And I am not asking to show a code How SO is written. My concern is the mechanism which SO has implemented.

Comment: well.. i think if your browser supports it.. it uses websockets. So event changes are pushed to you instead of you trying to check for changes.

Comment: Have you tried debugging where in your application the "few seconds" are lost? Is it a lot of data you are sending? Is it the server taking ages to process? I think in the case of SO it's all down to optimization.

Comment: @Tallmaris, I wanted to ask a question with regard to your comment "Means that: Does it checks for some DB events whenever any entry made to DB for the related questions or answers?" But kamituel wrote in his comment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In general, SO uses web sockets to provide responsive, fast updates. If you want to learn more, have a look at, on example, [socket.io](http://socket.io/) (which is a nice wrapper for web sockets providing fallback for older browsers) or [MDN doc](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/WebSockets) on websockets. You can also go all-in and read the [RFC](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6455).

Here is a sample request (from Chrome Developer Tools):

```
Request URL:ws://sockets.ny.stackexchange.com/
Request Method:GET
Request Headersview source
Cache-Control:no-cache
Connection:Upgrade
Host:sockets.ny.stackexchange.com
Sec-WebSocket-Extensions:x-webkit-deflate-frame
Sec-WebSocket-Key:PcP0d7X/j2DJkw2mx+116w==
Sec-WebSocket-Version:13
Upgrade:websocket
```

And response:

```
Status Code:101 Switching Protocols
Connection:Upgrade
Sec-WebSocket-Accept: ...
Upgrade:websocket
```

Comment: In fact if you have web inspector on the network tab and refresh SO, you should able to find an request send to ws://sockets.(ny|??).stackexchange.com/

Comment: @user1600124 - I was attaching some example headers as we spoke ;)

Comment: Means that: Does it checks for some DB events whenever any entry made to DB for the related questions or answers?

Comment: @NullVoid - oh, I cannot tell that, I'm not on the SO team ;) But yes, either they have some DB notifications, or they've implemented this on aplication level. Maybe [this link](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10369/which-tools-and-technologies-are-used-to-build-the-stack-exchange-network) will shed some light.

Comment: I seen the H/W and S/W configuration. What a deadly combination of all these !?

Comment: @NullVoid - well, looks like it's a pretty big site ;)

Comment: From an optimization point of view, what they may have done is split the request/response from the actual action. So for example an upvote will make an ajax request which will be aknowledged, queed and then answered (fast). Later the queue is processed and the DB actually updated... in case of errors, I imagine, a notification is sent to the user (either through websocket or other methods)... Just a guess, tho, since I am not on the SO team (but that's a way I did things in the past)